# Issue in database connection

Tags: c#, .net

I have made a database on vs 2013 c# project. I have added a connection, but when I run the program the connection automatically gets closed. I have put `con.open()` in code but it gives an error that it cannot open connection. Why ???

Microsoft SQL Server Database File (SqlClient) this is my database datasource.

This image before i build solotuion connection is good it is connected you can see green plug sign highlighted with red box:

[image]

After I rebuild solution the connection automatically breaks.  How to resolve this?

[image]

Comment: This is most probably due to the fact that your database file is part of the solution and therefore gets overwritten in the output directory when you build the solution. SQL Server databases (*.mdf) are generally not seen in the solution explorer hierarchy. You may want to switch to SDF intsead.

Comment: there is no option in visual studio 2013 to create sdf any other solution

Answer (score 0):

Your question is overly broad, thus the answer is a bit generic. Pertinent to your project, you may use the file-based Databases, like `SQLite` mentioned by member @dotNET , or `SQL Server CE` (Compact Edition, extension .sdf) placed in `App_Data` folder of your project Workspace. The connections string would be rather straightforward, like: `conString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|MySqlCeDb.sdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"`.

Hope this may help.